# 400 Bad Request while passing JSON using POST in REST

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vb.net, rest

I have a simple HTML File. I want to send some data from front end to Rest Service but I am not able to do so. Have I missed something. Kindly help me. How to pass JSON and in which format I need to pass.

HTML FILE:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="ClickMe!"/> 
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnGetResponse").click(function()
    {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
// IS this URL Correct
        url: "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/usercheckboxes",
// IS this Data Json Correct Format
        data: {
          checkBoxProp : "hello"
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert('hello');
        },
        failure: function(response) 
        {
            alert('fail');
        }
       });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sample REST Code:

```
 Public Function CheckBoxDetails(requestData As CheckBoxDataObjRequest) As CheckBoxDataObjResponse Implements iSMS_Rest.CheckBoxDetails
        Dim res As New CheckBoxDataObjResponse
        Return res
    End Function
```

REST Class:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

<DataContract>
Public Class CheckBoxDataObjRequest

    <DataMember(Name:="checkBoxProp")>
    Private checkBox As String
    Public Property checkBoxProp() As String
        Get
            Return checkBox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            checkBox = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class

<DataContract>
Public Class CheckBoxDataObjResponse

 <DataMember(Name:="checkBoxProp")>
    Private checkBox As String
    Public Property checkBoxProp() As String
        Get
            Return checkBox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            checkBox = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

REST Interface:

```
 <OperationContract(Name:="CheckBoxDetails")>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="usercheckboxes")>
    Function CheckBoxDetails(requestData As CheckBoxDataObjRequest) As CheckBoxDataObjResponse
```

Web Config:

```
<service name="SMS_LoginUser_Rest">
        <endpoint address="v1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="iSMS_LoginUser_Rest" bindingConfiguration="bw" behaviorConfiguration="web" name="restful"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

Comment: I think only service name will be enough you dont need the host and name'

Comment: When I send an empty JSON. I mean when I keep `data: {}` in Ajax, In this case I am able to hit the break point in my Rest Service.

Comment: Can you kindly check the data format and URL. Am I doing rest of the things correctly?